# gnuplot arrow coordinates (x,y) error columns

Tags: gnuplot

I'm new in gnuplot and my aim is to plot arrows between each data coordinate. My ".dat" file has only two columns, separated by a single tab, where the first is the X and the second is the Y component. The head should be set in the next coordinate.

```
582.761 -326.288
574.806 -327.915
```

My command was:

```
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2 with vectors head filled
```

I only can obtain the following error message:

> Not enough columns for this style

Sorry for the dumb question, but I couldn't understand neither the documentation nor other questions in the same subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `help vectors` you will see that `with vectors` plotting style requires 4 values.
And if I understand your question correctly I guess you want to plot arrows from one data line to the next data line, correct?

By the expression `(x0=x1,x1=$1,x0)` you keep the previous `x` value in `x0` and the current value in `x1`, but you're plotting `x0`. Same for `y0` and `y1`. And `(x1-x0)` and `(y1-y0)` are simply the `delta x` and `delta y` values which you need for the `with vectors` plotting style.

**Code:**

```
### vectors from data line to the next
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   1
2   2
3   5
2   4
1   2
EOD

x1=y1=NaN
plot $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(x1-x0):(y1-y0) w vectors head filled notitle

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @theozh! Your answer is helpful and fulfilled properly my necessity.